# Complex Modulus Intergrable iff Real Part and Imaginary Part Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

In this document, [http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/handouts/real.pdf](http://people.math.gatech.edu/%7Eheil/handouts/real.pdf).

After **Definition 3.5**, it is mentioned that

> Note that $|\operatorname{Re}(f)|, |\operatorname{Im}(f)| \leq |\operatorname{Re}(f)| + |\operatorname{Im}(f)|$. Therefore
> $$\int_{E} |f| < \infty \iff \int_{E} |\operatorname{Re}(f)|, \int_{E} |\operatorname{Im}(f)| < \infty$$

I managed to show both of the direction, but I am not sure how to show an important assumption in my proof, which is:

- Forward Direction

If $|f|$ is integrable, then use the Integral Comparison Test:

Suppose $\operatorname{Re}(f)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ are measurable function (**which I am not sure how to show**)

A nonnegative integrable function $|f|$ is integrable over $E$ and dominates $\operatorname{Re}(f)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f)$

We have $|\operatorname{Re}(f)| \leq |f| $ and $|\operatorname{Im}(f)| \leq |f|$.

That is, $\operatorname{Re}(f)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ are integrable over $E$.

- Backward Direction

When $\left| \operatorname{Re} (f) \right| $ and $\left| \operatorname{Im}(f) \right|$ are integrable, which means that $\int_{E} \left| \operatorname{Re}(f) \right| < \infty$ and $\int_{E} \left| \operatorname{Im} (f) \right|< \infty$.

Since we have:
$$\left| \operatorname{Re}(f) \right|, \left| \operatorname{Im}(f) \right| \leq |f| \leq \left| \operatorname{Re}(f) \right| + \left| \operatorname{Im}(f) \right|$$

Hence, by Monotonicity of Integration. (**Here, we require $|f|$ to be measurable but I am not sure how to justify**).

$$
    \begin{align*}
        \int_{E} |f| & \leq \int_{E} |\operatorname{Re}(f)| + |\operatorname{Im}(f)| \\ 
        & = \int_{E} |\operatorname{Re}(f)| + \int_{E} |\operatorname{Im}(f)| \\
        & < \infty
    \end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions $z \to |z|, z \to \Re z$ and $z \to \Im z$ are continuous, hence Borel measurable from $\mathbb C \to \mathbb R$. Compose with $f$ to see that  $|f|, \Re f $ and  $\Im f$ are measurable.

Comment: Thank you, but the $f$ does not seem to be measurable by default. Do you mind explaining how it is shown?

Comment: You cannot talk about intergrals of non-measurable functions. So your questions is meaningless without any measuarability assumption. @Benjamin